# django-secretballot : How to get a QuerySet order_by votes score?

Tags: django

I have a model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)

secretballot.enable_voting_on(Question)
```

all work well. But if I want these question sorted by their votes score,

just like reddit style. run:

```
Question.objects.filter(Terms_id=1).order_by('total_name')
```

get this error:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'total_name' into field. Choices are: title, body, id, votes

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Try `.order_by('-votes')`

Comment: @Rohan : `.order_by('-votes')` not work. It return a querySet which contains all votes: `[<Question: dadfaet>, <Question: werwr>, <Question: zzxsddds>, <Question: some girl>, <Question: zzz,ggghhh>, <Question: some girl>, <Question: zzz,ggg
hhh>, <Question: some girl>, <Question: zzz,ggghhh>, <Question: zzz,ggghhh>]`

Comment: But isn't that sorted by votes?

Comment: I want it sorted by votes socre, hightest voted score question object at first , then second .... like reddit, but `order_by('votes')` return a QuerySet whith duplicated objects

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Question.objects.order_by('-total_upvotes').distinct()
```

Distinct will remove the duplicates.